# More efficient multi threading possible?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I have a Concurrent Hash Map where I need to update the value in a loop.
Although , the concurrent map itself is thread safe but the add operation is not atomic and hence I need to add the synchronized block. Please correct me if I am wrong here.

The question is if this code can be synchronized more efficiently using locks etc.?  I am getting the values from a blocking queue.

Here is the code:

```
// running in a loop

String i =  (String) queue.take();

synchronized(this) {
    if(hashmap.containsKey(i)) {

        hashmap.put(i, hashmap.get(i) + 1);

    } else {    
        hashmap.put(i, 1);      
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you see that a `ConcurrentMap`'s `.add()` was not atomic? Also, do you know that it has an operation called `putIfAbsent()`? And Java 8 has even more operations (look at `.compute()` for instance)

Comment: Yes , you are right I can use putifAbsent,..did not check for that method. But is there a way to synchronize this more efficiently if lets say it was just a hashmap?

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap` is more efficient than a `synchronize` block, when you have huge concurrent operation, e.g 32 at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent` and `AtomicInteger` values to implement your counter map without synchronization on the whole map:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String,AtomicInteger> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

String key = ...
map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new AtomicInteger()).incrementAndGet();
```

Comment: Guava's `AtomicLongMap` is an abstraction of this idiom (Java 6 based).